# Use SSRS DataSource Name in Expression

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS 2019.  In my report I would like to include a text box in the header saying what environment the data was produced from.  We have development, test and production environments. The shared data sources  follow a specific naming standard that makes it easy to identify if they are dev, test or prod.  So I'd like to say if the shared data source is like "*dev*" or "*test*" then display a message at the top of the report, otherwise hide it.

Is there any way I can reference the shared data source in an expression in the report?  And I don't mean the name you give the data source in the report, I mean the name of the shared data source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the DataSources global collection.  The expression would look something like this:

```
=DataSources!DataSource1.DataSourceReference
```

This will return the path of the data source.  You may need to publish to the report server for it to display properly as Microsoft states that it's not available in local preview or that you may get different values in preview vs being deployed.

Comment: PERFECT!!  Thanks very much!!